# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre ' comillas simples y ` tildes invertidas (backquote/backtick)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hola quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estos dos tipos de comillas, sucede que con '' no obtiene el keyCode y con `` si y no entiendo por qué.
A continuación el código de la línea en donde se presenta el escenario.

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

El HTML y SCRIPT

```
<body>  
  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    console.log(audio);
  });
</script>
</body>
```

con ''

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con ``

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Comment: En términos prácticos es lo mismo, y no te agarra keyCode porque al usar comillas sencillas nuevamente estás cerrando el string, después concatenando (erróneamente) una variable llamara ${e.keyCode} y después reabres el string. Para que puedas tener strings con comillas dentro de otros strings, es como se usa la combinación de comillas simples y dobles, como está en tu selector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cuando utilizas las tildex invertidas ``, no estas representando una cadena en sí, sino que estas utilizando una función agregada en ES2015, llamada platilla de cadenas de texto, o template literals en inglés.

Esta caracteristica te permite crear cadenas de texto utilizando varias líneas de texto y meter valores dentro de la misma utilizando `${expression}` que es lo que estás haciendo en tu ejemplo, el cual evalúa `${e.keycode}` antes de crear la cadena de texto final.

Esta función sirve para no tener que concatenar cadenas utilizando el operador `+` te pongo un ejemplo:

Antes de las plantillas tendrías que hacer esto:

```
console.log("Hola " + nombre + ", bienvenido al sitio.")
```

Y con plantillas de texto puedes hacerlo más facil:

```
console.log(`Hola ${nombre}, bienvenido al sitio.`)
```

Ambos ejemplos van a agregar la variable `nombre` a tu cadena, no se ve mucho el beneficio en este pequeño ejemplo, pero al buscar cadenas más largas o de multiples líneas, resultan una herramienta muy útil.

Te dejo un [link al sitio de Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) con mas información sobre esta nueva función en JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

La tilde invertida sirve para utilizar la carterística denominada [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) de ES2015

Lo que permite es utilizar variables que pueden ser referenciadas en medio del string sin tener que partirlo en varias secciones concatenadas por el símbolo `+`

Ejemplo

```js
    let nombre = 'Juan';
    
    // Esto
    let saludo = 'Hola ' + nombre +  '. ¿Cómo estás?';
    console.log(saludo);
    
    // equivale a:
    let saludo2 = `Hola ${nombre}. ¿Cómo estás?`;
    console.log(saludo2);
```

En tu caso el error es que al usar comillas simples `''` la cadena se evaluará tal cual está escrita, sin evaluar las variables dentro de `${}` y por lo tanto obtendrás lo sgte:

```js
var e = {
  keyCode: 13
};

console.log('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

Mientras que lo correcto sería

```js
var e = {
  keyCode: 13
};

console.log(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```