# Por que mi código funcionó con el siguiente símbolo: (`ejemplo`) pero no con ('ejemplo2')?

Tags: javascript, dom

Mi código inicial  fue el siguiente, y no funcionó

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) 
    { 

const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keycode}"]');

if (!audio) return;
audio.play(); 
 });
```

pero una vez cambiadas las comillas simples, por las otras, todo corrió perfecto.

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

Desde mi perspectiva ambas eran exactamente lo mismo, comillas simples, estoy haciendo un proyecto personal para aprender así que tuve la oportunidad de checar el producto final de lo que estoy construyendo y tras analizar bien la linea de código, vi que es era la única diferencia, de no ser asi... cuando y como me iba  dar cuenta que ese era el problema? Esto puede tener mayores efectos en códigos futuros, apreciaría la ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si vas a utilizar las tildes invertidas (``), no estas representando una cadena, estas usando una función agregada en ES2015, conocida como "Plantilla de Cadenas de Texto", o en inglés "Template Literals"... Copio el link de referencia donde alguien hizo la misma pregunta:

[¿Qué diferencia hay entre ' comillas simples y ` tildes invertidas (backquote/backtick)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106091/qu%C3%A9-diferencia-hay-entre-comillas-simples-y-tildes-invertidas-backquote-ba)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ahora entiendo :)

Answer (score 1):

Esta función sirve para no tener que concatenar cadenas utilizando el operador + te pongo un ejemplo:

Sin las comillas tendrías que hacer esto:

```
console.log("Hola " + Variable + ",  Mucho gusto.")
```

Con las comillas tendrías que hacer esto:

```
console.log(`Hola ${Variable},  Mucho gusto.`)
```

Comment: No es shell, OP habla de javascript, según las etiquetas.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración ya he editado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que intentaste

`const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keycode}"]');`

no funciona porque has incluido una expresión entre marcadores `${expresión}` dentro de un par de apóstrofes, lo que hace que este sea interpretado de forma literal y no como el objeto o valor al que hace referencia.

en su lugar podrías haber usado

`const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="'+ e.keycode + '"]');`

En el segundo caso, reemplazaste los apóstrofes por el [acento grave](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_grave) que en inglés algunos llaman "backtick". Este caracter es usado para delimitar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

De la liga anterior

> Las plantillas de cadena de texto se delimitan con el caracter (sic) de comillas o tildes invertidas (` `) ([grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)) , en lugar de las comillas simples o dobles. Las plantillas de cadena de texto pueden contener marcadores, indentificados (sic) por el signo de pesos, y envueltos en llaves (`${expresión}`). Las expresiones contenidas en los marcadores, junto con el texto entre ellas, son enviados como argumentos a una función. La función por defecto simplemente concatena las partes para formar una única cadena de texto. Si hay una expresión antes de la plantilla de cadena de texto (i.e. `tag`),  llamamos a esta plantilla de cadena de texto "plantilla de cadena de texto con etiqueta". En este caso, la expresión de etiqueta  (típicamente una función) es llamada a partir de la cadena resultante de procesar la plantilla de cadena de texto, que luego puede ser manipulada antes de ser devuelta.

Comment: Muy útil información, gracias por la ayuda.