# Cómo usar variables dentro de una cadena en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Cuando ejecuto este codigo obtengo `Hola ${nombre} ${text}`

Pero quiero obtener `Hola bauti que`

```
function saludo(nombre,text){
    console.log("Hola ${nombre} ${text}")
}
saludo("bauti","que");
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué diferencia hay entre ' comillas simples y \` tildes invertidas (backquote/backtick)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106091/qu%c3%a9-diferencia-hay-entre-comillas-simples-y-tildes-invertidas-backquote-ba)

Answer (score 2):

Para que Javascript te reconozca las variables dentro de la cadena, tienes que usar `` ` `` (backtikc) en vez de `"` como carácter delimitador. Si usas un editor que coloree el código, te darás cuenta enseguida.

Además, es recomendable que formatees el código: pasa la llave de cierre de la función a una nueva línea, tabula la instrucción dentro de la función, y finalízala con punto y coma.

```
function saludo(nombre,text){
    alert(`Hola ${nombre} ${text}`);
}

saludo("bauti", "que");
```